# What are the conventions regarding notation for variables denoting vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, notation, vectors

Should a variable denoting a vector always be in upright font, even when it is a Greek letter?

When denoting vector variables, I have noticed that it is common to use a bold, non-italic, lowercase character, such as **a**, **b**, etc. I use latex for the few equations I write and I have noticed that it is quite cumbersome to create non-italicized lowercase Greek letters. This makes me wonder if Greek letter variables always should be italicized and it would be wrong to force an upright Greek letter for a vector variable.

What is the preferred way of typesetting a vector variable when it is represented by a Greek character? Should it be in italics and bold, or upright and bold?

---

#### Update

[image]

Examples, from left to right: upright, bold+upright, italic, italic+bold. The upright letters are using a slightly different font in this example.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; do you think of for instance $\beta$ as being italicized? How would you make it non-italicized?

Comment: Not sure if there is a standard.  For what it's worth, unless the context makes it clear what everything is, I like to include the arrow as in $\vec v$

Comment: @Lovsovs I added an image to better illustrate my question.

Comment: @lulu I noticed that representation, but I kind of like the bold-fonted version better. Although, since latex seems to have problems with both upright Greek letters and bolded math, I might just move back to the arrow representation, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: I agree with @lulu ; whenever it's not clear by the context that a variable is a vector, I put a small arrow above it.

Comment: I am not a fan of the notation $\vec v$; it's rather cumbersome after a while

Comment: The notation conventions vary from field to field and from country to country, so it is hard to imagine a definitive answer. I'd say that the best practice would be to take a look at other publications in your domain and try to write your articles in a manner that the vector nature of your variables can be easily guessed from context.

Comment: In economics (and I suppose many other fields) it is quite common not to use any special notation to distinguish vectors from scalars, e.g. just write $\beta=(\beta_1,\ldots, \beta_n)$. This seems neater to me, and leaves overlines etc free for other uses.

Comment: In France, Greek letters are traditionally upright.

Comment: @smcc Thanks, that's the solution I went with in the end. It also avoids any ambiguity when for example transposing a variable with a line or arrow above it.

Answer (score 1):

As you have noted, forcing Greek letters to be "non-italicized" is not very standard (if you want to use it anyway, see *Bernard*'s comment below).

I'd do one of three things:

1. Bold: $\pmb{\beta}$
2. Overlined: $\overline{\beta}$
3. With an arrow: $\vec{\beta}$

To me, the bold option (no. 1) reminds me more of matrix notation, so I'd personally use either 2. or 3.

Comment: It exists in quite a few font package, and is often known as  `frenchmath`. To mention a few ones: `fourier`, `kpfonts`, `Minion Pro`, `mathdesign`, `newpx` or `newtx`.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, great to know!

Comment: Thanks, in the end I went with the same notation as for any other variable, an italic beta with normal font weight and no added arrows or lines, $\beta$. The other solutions sometimes looked a bit cramped or unclear, such as when transposing the matrix, $\vec{\beta}^T$. It is possible that I can get around that playing with the space between characters, but I don't want to spend too much time optimizing that.

Comment: @cheflo Probably a good decision. Note that you could also use $\underline{\beta}$ for vectors and $\underline{\underline{\beta}}$ for matrices. $\underline{\underline{\beta}}^T$ looks pretty nice IMO.